# Getting data from other database

Tags: django, django-admin

I would like to make a question about a problem that I have, and my lack of experience I'm not sure if it would be the best option.

Currently we have installed in our server "OCS inventory reports", which keeps an updated inventory of all computers that we have.
Our intention is to use these data to be viewed on our django admin site.
First,i will create all the models in ouer application.
When you create a computer in the admin site and save it, the information in the OCS database will be imported to ouer database.

I Don't know if it would be the best way.
I dont know all the possibilities that django provides.
It would be efficient to import the data each time a new object be created?
Any chance of displaying information in the admin interface without importing it to my application and directly attack the other database?
(sorry for my bad english)

Comment: What's the question here? You need to be more specific about your problem? Are you asking how you can use multiple databases or how you can manually insert rows into a separate database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want django admin to only ready the OCS database.

First of all you need to define the external database in the DATABASES settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        ... django db settings here ...
    },
    'ocs_db': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'read_default_file': '/path/to/my.cnf',
        },
    }
}
```

You can give `python manage.py inspectdb --database ocs_db` a try; 
inspectdb looks up the tables on the db and dumps the model definition as a python module.
If this does not work then you have to do it manually.

Then you want django not to manage that table (so that no rows will be deleted, and no operation against the table will be done), you can do that via the Meta managed option.

I suggest you to write a base class with this option (and eventually other customisations you need for all OCS models).

```
class OCSBaseModel(models.Model):

    def save(self):
        """
        avoid inserts / edits from model
        """
        return 

    class Meta():
        abstract = True
        managed = False


class Workstation(OCSBaseModel):
    ...
```

As last step you need to instruct Django to use the right db for the OCS models.

For this you need to write a database router as documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#automatic-database-routing)

or implement a django model manager for OCS models that marks every querysets to the database.
eg.

```
class OCSModelManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(OCSModelManager, self).get_query_set().using('ocs_db')
```

Please note that I did not test any of this code ;)